# PHP formatting in VSCode on remote Workspace without using Composer

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, formatting, remote-server

My Setup: Ubuntu 20 with PHP and Composer
My Editor: VSCode with SSH FS extension to access remote workspace.
My Task: do some PHP stuff, mainly Wordpress Themes
My Problem: no PHP Formatter extension works on the remote Workspace

I tried to use: PHP-CS-fixer, Prettier with PHP plugin, phpfmt, phpcs, PHP Formatter...
Some of them will even not work on my local Workspace.

I can't install new Code on the remote Server (Composer), so i need a way to format PHP files just out of the Box like HTML or JS.

But meanwhile i think, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use Ubuntu to connect to the server and mount that folder in workspace, let VSC think it is a real local folder :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with most formatting extensions is that they expect the files to be on a local drive, as in being mounted outside VS Code, including network shares by any NodeJS program (and therefore VS Code extensions). The extension uses the extension API's FileSystemProvider to provide FS access to VS Code. It is only [recently](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48034) that they added a way for one extension to use file systems provided by other extensions, and it's even [more recent](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123115) that they started pushing extensions to make use of this.

Sadly enough, not every extension developer might start using it, and it's especially tricky for extension that use native/external programs. That includes most language-servers and formatters.

For your use case, there are two solutions though:

- Mount the folder on the OS level (e.g. [sshfs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS)) and just open it as a regular directory in VS Code, as another answer suggested
- Use VS Code's [Remote SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh), which actually runs the extensions on the server, therefore skipping the whole "files aren't on a local drive" problem